# Spring SFTP inbound chanel adapter delete local file

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have configured spring SFTP to pool the files into local from remote path, to process some jobs, then delete the local & remote file both.

below configuration works fine, except the local file delete, i didn't find any configuration to delete the local file, like `delete-remote-files="true"`

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory"
    p:host="${sftp.host}"
    p:port="${sftp.port}"
    p:user="${sftp.username}"
    p:password="${sftp.password}"
    p:allowUnknownKeys="${sftp.allowUnknownKeys}" />

<int:channel id="sftpChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="sftpInboundAdapter"
    channel="sftpChannel"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    remote-directory="${sftp.remotedir}"
    local-directory="${sftp.localdir}"
    auto-create-local-directory="true"      
    delete-remote-files="true" 
    filename-pattern="*.TXT">
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="${quartz.pick.repeatInterval}" max-messages-per-poll="${sftp.msg.per.poll}">
    <int:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
</int:poller>   

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-rollback expression="@acceptOnceFilter.remove(payload)"/>
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<bean id="acceptOnceFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="sftpChannel" ref="msgHandler" method="handleMessage"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="fileNameGenerator" class="org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultFileNameGenerator" />
```

Here, an service activator invoked, when an file transferred from remote to local.

How can i configure to delete the local file when service activator completes the job?

EDIT: payload delete from remote and local both are resolved with below changes:

```
<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="payload.delete()" channel="nullChannel"/>
    <int:after-rollback expression="@acceptOnceFilter.remove(payload)"/>
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inbound adapters never take any action (on their own) after the message is sent to the flow; it doesn't know anything about the downstream flow topology - async handoffs etc. The remote deletion is done after the file is fetched and before the message is sent.

Since you're already using a pseudo transaction, and doing everything on the poller thread, you can do the delete with an `after-commit-expression`.

The other technique is to add a `request-handler-advice` to the final consumer (service activator in your case). That is demonstrated in [the `retry-and-more` sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more).

**EDIT:**

In response to your comments below; no it's not possible to do 2 things with SpEL - however, you can use

```
<int:after-commit expression="payload" channel="postProcess"/>
```

and do whatever you want on the flow downstream of the `postProcess` channel.

However, it's not clear to me why you want to remove the file from the filter for both success and failure - you should just use an `AcceptAllFileListFilter` instead.

By the way, I don't see your `acceptOnceFilter` being used anywhere here - did you intend to configure it into the `local-filter` attribute?

Comment: Thank you Gary, let me try your solution, is there an way to perform two task through expression, like: 1)Delete the payload, and 2)remove payload from acceptOnceFilter.

Comment: it's working, (1) file delete resolved using `after-commit-expression`, could you please mention about remove payload from acceptOnceFilter?

Comment: tried with after-commit-expression="payload.delete() and @acceptOnceFilter.remove(payload)", where only delete works fine.

Comment: Russel when i write an expression in after-rollback as `payload.renameTo(payload.name + '.error')` it's renaming in local directory and file was deleted in remote path, what i expected is to rename in remote directory. what am doing wrong?

Comment: No; the payload is the local file the remote operation is over before we send a message to the channel; the message handling has no way to interact with the remote server. You need to send a message (from the `after-rollback`) to an SFTP [outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) and use the `mv` command to rename the remote file. It's deleted in the remote directory because you have `delete-remote-files="true" `.

Comment: May be you have an answer for this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336599/spring-sftp-read-file-lock)