# Spring Integration DSL for SFTP Outbound with delete

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration-sftp

I'm using

- Sprint Integration(File, SFTP, etc) 4.3.6
- Spring Boot 1.4.3
- Spring Integration Java DSL 1.1.4

and I'm trying to set up an SFTP outbound adapter that would allow me move a file to a directory on the remote system and also remove or rename the file in my local system.

So, for instance I would like to place a file, **a.txt**, in a local directory and have it SFTP'ed to a remote server in the directory **inbound**. Once the transfer is complete I would like to have the local copy of **a.txt** deleted, or renamed.

I was toying with a couple of ways to this. So here is my common SessionFactory for the test.

```
protected SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> buildSftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    sessionFactory.setHost("localhost");
    sessionFactory.setUser("user");
    sessionFactory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    sessionFactory.setPassword("pass");
    CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> cachingSessionFactory = new CachingSessionFactory<>(sessionFactory, 1);
    return cachingSessionFactory;
}
```

This is a transformer that I have to add some of the headers to the message

```
@Override
public Message<File> transform(Message<File> source) {
    System.out.println("here is the thing : "+source);
    File file = (File)source.getPayload();
    Message<File> transformedMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file)
            .copyHeaders(source.getHeaders())
            .setHeaderIfAbsent(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, file)
            .setHeaderIfAbsent(FileHeaders.FILENAME, file.getName())
            .build();
    return transformedMessage;
}
```

I then have an integration flow that uses a poller to watch a local directory and invoke this :

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pushTheFile(){
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s -> s.file(new File(DIR_TO_WATCH))
                            .patternFilter("*.txt").preventDuplicates(),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
            .transform(outboundTransformer)
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(this.buildSftpSessionFactory())
                    .remoteFileSeparator("/")
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .remoteDirectory("inbound/")
            )
            .get();
}
```

This works fine, but leaves the local file. Any ideas on how to have this remove local file after the upload completes? Should I be looking at the `SftpOutboundGateway` instead?

Thanks in advance!

Artem's answer worked perfectly!  Here is a quick example that deletes the local file after it is pushed.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pushTheFile(){
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s -> s.file(new File(DIR_TO_WATCH))
                            .patternFilter("*.txt").preventDuplicates(),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
            .transform(outboundTransformer)
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(this.buildSftpSessionFactory())
                    .remoteFileSeparator("/")
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .remoteDirectory("inbound/"), c -> c.advice(expressionAdvice(c))
            )
            .get();
}

@Bean
public Advice expressionAdvice(GenericEndpointSpec<FileTransferringMessageHandler<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>> c) {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setOnSuccessExpression("payload.delete()");
    advice.setOnFailureExpression("payload + ' failed to upload'");
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}
```

Comment: May be this will help you- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247467/spring-sftp-inbound-chanel-adapter-delete-local-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can use several approaches.

All of them are based on the fact that you do something else with the original request message for the `Sftp.outboundAdapter()`.

1. `.publishSubscribeChannel()` allows you to send the same message to several subscribers, when the second will receive it only the first one finishes its work. By default, if you don't specify `Executor`
2. `routeToRecipients()` allows you make the same result but via different component.
3. `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` - you add this one to the `.advice()` of the `Sftp.outboundAdapter()` endpoint definition - the second `.handle()` argument and perform `file.delete()` via `onSuccessExpression`:

   ```
   .transform((Integer p) -> p * 2, c -> c.advice(this.expressionAdvice()))
   ```

Comment: Thank you Artem for the response.  I'm trying to run with the 3rd option that you mentioned, but I'm a little confused. The `Sftp.outboundAdapter()` doesn't seem to have an `advice()` method.  I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but can you help point me in a direction?

Comment: True, you have to take a look to the `Consumer` arg of the `.handle()`:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#endpointConfig

Comment: I see what you are saying now.  I'll post an example once I have it cleaned up.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Adding an example in the post

Comment: @ArtemBilan what if Sftp.outboundAdapter() failed to upload file. second subscribe still getting message for processing. is there a way to stop it?

Comment: Sorry, it sounds like it deserves its own SO thread with much more info.

Comment: @ArtemBilan
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63489690/spring-dsl-integration-flow-publishing-message-after-error-in-outbound-adaptor