# Spring DSL Integration Flow publishing message after error in outbound adaptor

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have a integration flow.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(
            Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
            .localDirectory(this.getlocalDirectory(config.getId()))
            .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .filter(new CompositeFileListFilter().addFilter(new LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter(config.getRegexFilter())))
            .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundDirectory())
            , e -> e.poller(
                    Pollers.cron(config.getCron())
                    .errorChannel(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL).errorHandler((ex) -> {
                        try {

                            this.destroy(String.valueOf(config.getId()));
                            configurationService.removeConfigurationChannelById(config.getId());
                            //loggin here

                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex1) {
                            Logger.getLogger(ExceptionAspect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
                        }
                    })
                    .advice(startup.scanRemoteDirectory())
            ))
            .transform(
                file -> util.transform((File) file, config.getSourceEncoding(), config.getTargetEncoding(), doEncoding, doZip))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                .subscribe(f -> {
                    f.handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(outboundSftp)
                        .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                        .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                        .remoteDirectory(config.getOutboundDirectory()), c -> c.advice(startup.deleteFileAdvice()));

                })
                .subscribe(f -> {

                    if(doArchive) {
                        f.handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
                            .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundArchiveDirectory()));
                    } else {
                        f.handle(m -> {});
                    }

                })
                .subscribe(f -> f
                    .handle(m -> {

                        // file transfer logging here
                        if(doArchive) {
                          // file archived logging here
                         }
                        }
                    })
                )
            )
            .get();
```

in 1st subscriber, if file is failed to upload it still printing logs that file is transferred but actually its not.

what i understand message will be pass to each on subscriber and when 1st subscriber complete its work it will sent to next one.

In my case first subscriber is actually fail to upload file. Advice is not removing file.

I did try few things.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(
                Sftp.inboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
               ..........
                ))
                .transform(....
                   )
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                    .subscribe(f -> {
                        f.handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(outboundSftp)
                            .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(config.getOutboundDirectory()), c -> c.advice(startup.deleteFileAdvice()));

                    }).publishSubcribeChannel(s -> s
                      .subscribe(f -> {

                        if(doArchive) {
                            f.handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(inboundSftp)
                                .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                                .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                                .remoteDirectory(config.getInboundArchiveDirectory()));
                        } else {
                            f.handle(m -> {});
                        }

                    })
                    .subscribe(f -> f
                        .handle(m -> {

                            // file transfer logging here
                            if(doArchive) {
                              // file archived logging here
                             }
                            }
                        })
                    )
                    )
                )
                .get();
```

I try to publish again after outboundAdapter subscriber, but in error it still published.

Also try to add .errorChannel in outboundAdapter subscriber, didn't work for me.

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2020-08-20 11:10:53,265 INFO c.t.i.s.I2SftpApplication - Starting I2SftpApplication on GSEUC5CG8393GR5 with PID 21636 (C:\Users\MuhammadUmair\IdeaProjects\i2sftpinboudservice\target\classes started by MuhammadUmair in C:\Users\MuhammadUmair\IdeaProjects\i2sftpinboudservice)
2020-08-20 11:10:53,269 INFO c.t.i.s.I2SftpApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-20 11:10:54,464 INFO o.s.i.c.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor - No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2020-08-20 11:10:54,478 INFO o.s.i.c.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor - No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2020-08-20 11:10:54,577 INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-20 11:10:54,584 INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-20 11:10:54,597 INFO o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-20 11:10:54,906 INFO o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-08-20 11:10:54,917 INFO o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2020-08-20 11:10:54,917 INFO o.a.c.c.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-20 11:10:54,917 INFO o.a.c.c.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2020-08-20 11:10:55,095 INFO o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-20 11:10:55,095 INFO o.s.w.c.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1705 ms
2020-08-20 11:10:56,920 INFO o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,243 INFO o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,415 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-08-20 11:10:57,416 INFO o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-08-20 11:10:57,416 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,416 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {message-handler:startup.resultFileHandler.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'fromSftpChannel' channel
2020-08-20 11:10:57,416 INFO o.s.i.c.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.fromSftpChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-08-20 11:10:57,417 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean 'startup.resultFileHandler.serviceActivator'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,422 INFO o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - started bean 'startup.sftpMessageSource.inboundChannelAdapter'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,441 INFO o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2020-08-20 11:10:57,498 INFO o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-08-20 11:10:57,508 INFO c.t.i.s.I2SftpApplication - Started I2SftpApplication in 9.228 seconds (JVM running for 13.133)
Registering an Integration Flow with id : 1
2020-08-20 11:10:57,689 INFO o.s.i.c.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.1.subFlow#2.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-08-20 11:10:57,690 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean '1.subFlow#2.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,691 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the '1.subFlow#0.channel#0' channel
2020-08-20 11:10:57,691 INFO o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 'application.1.subFlow#0.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-08-20 11:10:57,691 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean '1.subFlow#2.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,691 INFO o.s.i.c.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.1.subFlow#1.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-08-20 11:10:57,691 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean '1.subFlow#1.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,691 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the '1.subFlow#0.channel#0' channel
2020-08-20 11:10:57,692 INFO o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 'application.1.subFlow#0.channel#0' has 2 subscriber(s).
2020-08-20 11:10:57,692 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean '1.subFlow#1.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,693 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {message-handler} as a subscriber to the '1.subFlow#0.channel#1' channel
2020-08-20 11:10:57,694 INFO o.s.i.c.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.1.subFlow#0.channel#1' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-08-20 11:10:57,694 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean '1.subFlow#0.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,694 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {bridge} as a subscriber to the '1.subFlow#0.channel#0' channel
2020-08-20 11:10:57,694 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean '1.subFlow#0.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,694 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the '1.channel#0' channel
2020-08-20 11:10:57,694 INFO o.s.i.c.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.1.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-08-20 11:10:57,694 INFO o.s.i.e.EventDrivenConsumer - started bean '1.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'
2020-08-20 11:10:57,700 INFO o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - started bean '1.org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean#0'
2020-08-20 11:10:58,017 INFO c.j.jsch - Connecting to *.*.*.114 port 22
2020-08-20 11:10:58,341 INFO c.j.jsch - Connection established
2020-08-20 11:10:58,672 INFO c.j.jsch - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
2020-08-20 11:10:58,673 INFO c.j.jsch - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
2020-08-20 11:10:58,674 INFO c.j.jsch - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
2020-08-20 11:10:58,728 INFO c.j.jsch - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
2020-08-20 11:10:58,815 INFO c.j.jsch - CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2020-08-20 11:10:58,823 INFO c.j.jsch - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
2020-08-20 11:10:59,036 INFO c.j.jsch - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
2020-08-20 11:10:59,038 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
2020-08-20 11:10:59,038 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
2020-08-20 11:10:59,039 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
2020-08-20 11:10:59,040 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
2020-08-20 11:10:59,040 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
2020-08-20 11:10:59,041 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
2020-08-20 11:10:59,042 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
2020-08-20 11:10:59,042 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
2020-08-20 11:10:59,042 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: 
2020-08-20 11:10:59,043 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server: 
2020-08-20 11:10:59,043 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
2020-08-20 11:10:59,044 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
2020-08-20 11:10:59,044 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
2020-08-20 11:10:59,045 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
2020-08-20 11:10:59,045 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2020-08-20 11:10:59,045 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
2020-08-20 11:10:59,045 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: none
2020-08-20 11:10:59,045 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: none
2020-08-20 11:10:59,045 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: 
2020-08-20 11:10:59,046 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client: 
2020-08-20 11:10:59,046 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
2020-08-20 11:10:59,047 INFO c.j.jsch - kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
2020-08-20 11:10:59,053 INFO c.j.jsch - SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
2020-08-20 11:10:59,053 INFO c.j.jsch - expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
2020-08-20 11:10:59,385 INFO c.j.jsch - ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
2020-08-20 11:10:59,389 INFO o.s.i.s.s.DefaultSftpSessionFactory - The authenticity of host '*.*.*.114' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 1f:3e:c9:5f:37:00:a1:00:ef:50:59:af:42:98:99:e9.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
2020-08-20 11:10:59,390 WARN c.j.jsch - Permanently added '*.*.*.114' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
2020-08-20 11:10:59,390 INFO c.j.jsch - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
2020-08-20 11:10:59,390 INFO c.j.jsch - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
2020-08-20 11:10:59,395 INFO c.j.jsch - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
2020-08-20 11:10:59,718 INFO c.j.jsch - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
2020-08-20 11:11:00,047 INFO c.j.jsch - Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
2020-08-20 11:11:00,047 INFO c.j.jsch - Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
2020-08-20 11:11:00,399 INFO c.j.jsch - Authentications that can continue: password
2020-08-20 11:11:00,399 INFO c.j.jsch - Next authentication method: password
2020-08-20 11:11:00,746 INFO c.j.jsch - Authentication succeeded (password).
Total Files: 1
2020-08-20 11:11:27,623 INFO c.t.i.s.s.LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter - [OB.xml] old size [null]  increased to [0]...
Total Files: 1
2020-08-20 11:11:29,636 INFO c.t.i.s.s.LastModifiedLsEntryFileListFilter - [OB.xml] old size [0]  increased to [38709]...
Total Files: 1
2020-08-20 11:11:34,256 INFO c.j.jsch - Connecting to *.*.*.115 port 22
2020-08-20 11:11:55,282 INFO c.t.i.c.f.a.LoggingAspect - log message Integration Name=CXML invoice DK Service Name=FileTransferService Source=External Source Interface=/home/umair/accruals/14minute/ Target=NA Target Interface=/home/umair/accruals/15minute/ Content ID=OB.xml Message ID=N/A Category=SUCCESS Timestamp=2020-08-20T11:11:55.281 Message=file OB.xml transferred
```

as per Artem Bilan suggestion, i have created a demo app and uploaded to git repo [here](https://github.com/Umair-Ansari/SpringDSLIntegrationFlow)

server configs are [here](https://github.com/Umair-Ansari/SpringDSLIntegrationFlow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/umair/sftp/schedules/ScheduledTask.java)

integration flow is defined [here](https://github.com/Umair-Ansari/SpringDSLIntegrationFlow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/umair/sftp/services/ChannelService.java)

README [file](https://github.com/Umair-Ansari/SpringDSLIntegrationFlow/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Any chances to see some logs from your on the matter? It is also not clear what part of your configuration you are talking about...

Comment: @ArtemBilan i am facing issue with first subscriber (one which contain Sftp.outboundAdapter(outboundSftp)). when i put wrong server config for output channel, subscriber after Sftp.outboundAdapter(outboundSftp)) gets invoked too.

Comment: Hm. Technically it is not possible since an `ignoreFailures` is `false` by default, so an exception is thrown from the failed subscribed. Would be great to see some logs with that error. Also: what Spring Integration version do you use?

Comment: @ArtemBilan spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE. Spring integration sftp 5.3.2.RELEASE. Spring integration ftp 5.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: If you say that there is an error during uploading, please, share a stack trace as an edit to your question. The logs are not readable in the comments.

Comment: Your logs doesn’t show any errors. If no exceptions, no failure. Any chances to have some small project to reproduce an issue?

Comment: ok ill create a small project.

Comment: @ArtemBilan i have upload demo project on git. link added in question

Comment: Thank you for sharing! But you know, your project is too big to digest it clearly. I have started it, but it does nothing. So, please, provide some README info what should I do with your project to reproduce.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Hi, thanks for giving your precious time. I am sorry, I did try to remove as must code as I can. I have also updated the README file. But if this still not help then ill move all configuration to properties file then. right now i remove incoming data and add a scheduler to add constant configurations.

Comment: Please, find my answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem:

```
@Bean
public Advice deleteFileAdvice() {

    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString(AppConstants.SUCCESS_EXPRESSION);
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}
```

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * If true, any exception will be caught and null returned.
 * Default false.
 * @param trapException true to trap Exceptions.
 */
public void setTrapException(boolean trapException) {
```

So, any exceptions from the message handler, including an SFTP conneciton failure is going to be swallowed. Therefore a request message is really moved to the next subscriber in your `publishSubcribeChannel` configuration.

Comment: I did add this flag, but its still moving to next channel.

Comment: Huh? It must `false` to re-throw an exception. Sorry, I’m not sure in your logic.

Comment: Its set to true as you suggest.

Comment: is there any alternate way that i can use?

Comment: No, i didn’t say that. I just showed you a JavaDoc explaining your behavior . Not sure what made you to go with `true`.

Comment: by default its false. i tried with both actually true and false. didn't make any difference. If its false it should return exception. But its not doing anything.

Comment: If it `false`, it throws an exception. See `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` source code. Can you, please, set a break point in the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.doInvoke()` ot investigate what is going on after that `callback.execute()` is called?

Comment: I debug this part of code. callback.execute() throws an Exception which is further throws because trapException is false. Exception is did print on console now but its still moving to next channel.

Comment: Who prints that exception into console? Can you debug now a `BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch()` to see what is going on with your subscribers. If you don't provide an `executor` for your publish-subscribe channel, then its `ignoreFailures` should do the trick to re-throw an exception and don't let the message to go for the next subscriber.